# Does "pendulum effect" apply to hang gliders or any aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, stability, flight-dynamics, roll

In discussion of aircraft roll stability in [FAA paragraph on dihedral effect](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53424/is-this-paragraph-about-the-dihedral-effect-in-the-faas-glider-flying-handbook) and in [keel effect](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26574/what-is-the-keel-effect) and in [Why are high wing aircraft more stable](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26396/why-are-high-wing-aircraft-more-stable) the question of pendulum effect arises.

This is usually described as center of gravity displaced laterally from below center of lift during a roll in a high wing airplane causing a rolling moment which restores wings to a level orientation.

[image]

[source](http://paperaeroplanes.com/blog/?p=22)

In any explanation you give, please consider the case of a hang glider which depends on weight shifting to control roll and pitch. (Don't need to discuss pitch)

[image]

[source](http://ushawks.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=2857)

Comment: All of the links in your question seem to point to answers that say "no, it's a myth".  Are there any counterexamples?  Right now I don't see any controversy.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I think the hang glider is a counterexample.

Comment: What is _usually_ understood as a "pendulum effect" is the normal (centered) fuselage contributing to the stability, i.e. creating a rolling moment by the virtue of being lower. This is a fallacy. But once you have misaligned lift and weight (hang glider), i.e. the lift vector not going through C.G., you'll have a rolling moment.

Comment: There is an aerodynamic effect (often called the Keel effect) that is sometimes called the "pendulum effect".  There is also the idea that a plane that "hangs" below a high wing is stable due to gravity pulling it upright.  I suspect that some things you find may be referring to one and some to the other.  Are you asking about one of these concepts specifically?  Wikipedia links it to the keel effect.

Comment: @BowlOfRed What I have read equates keel effect and pendulum effect, so both are in question.

Comment: The fallacy is to think that the hangglider pilot shifts the center of gravity: He can't, because of the conservation of momentum. Instead, he shifts the wing and with it the center of lift to the opposite side. All rolling motion is around the center of gravity so the weight has no pull on the rolling moment (pun intended).

Comment: @user207141 and PeterKampf and others-- all this attention to what is the *immediate* (before any roll) effect on the combined CG of glider plus pilot, when pilot exerts force with muscles to intentionally "shift" to side, as seen from a reference frame originally moving simultaneous with glider, is "interesting", but kind of peripheral to "pendulum stability".   In fact I'd even suggest that *any* discussion of pilot intentionally shifting to side is peripheral.

Comment: (ctd) Because it's obvious enough *why* the pilot's body intentionally shifting far to one side creates a roll torque.

Comment: @PeterKämpf and user207141 and others -- (ctd) A more interesting question is in turning flight, does the hang glider pilot have to exert any muscle force just to keep himself centered in the control frame, rather than falling to the "low side", and if so, is this evidence of some sort of "pendulum stability" effect? And would this same effect exist to any degree if the pilot relaxed all muscle force and allowed himself to swing freely? In the latter case, would it make any difference as to whether the flexible hang strap attached to the glider above or below the glider's CG?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a proper discussion, we should first define what a pendulum is. Only then can be established if such an effect can exist in airplanes.

Let's base the definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum). It says that

> A pendulum is a weight suspended from a pivot so that it can swing freely.

Maybe it is also worth to look closer what a [pivot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pivot) is: A thing on which something turns.

So the pendulum is fixed to a fulcrum which keeps it suspended and allows it to swing freely. The ideal pendulum has all its mass in its massive bob and, therefore, pivot and center of gravity are **not** in the same place. If the center of gravity and the pivot would fall together, a pendulum could only rotate but not swing. And that swinging motion is what the pendulum is all about.

Now for airplanes: Here we have no pivot. All rotation can only happen around the center of gravity. This is equivalent to the pendulum with no length which is no pendulum any more. But what about hang gliders? Using Pilothead's sketch let's consider how a hangglider starts a rolling motion and compare that to how a glider does it. The top two sketches show each in steady straight flight while the bottom two sketches show both initiating a roll to the right:

[image: Comparison of hang glider and sailplane]

In both cases, a lateral imbalance is needed to create a rolling moment (red round arrow). While the pilot of the hang glider shifts the whole wing sideways, the glider pilot commands a lift difference between both wings using ailerons. Note the shift of the hangglider to the right and with it the center of lift in the lower left sketch: The center of gravity stays where it is due to the conservation of momentum while the pilot will shift slightly to the left.  In case of the glider, no such lateral shift of the craft occurs; instead the distribution of lift is shifted in order to create the imbalance. The effect is the same: A lateral displacement between weight and lift which causes a rolling moment. Rolling happens around the center of gravity (because of [conservation of momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum#Conservation) again) and in all cases there is no displacement between the pivot point and the working point of the weight, because both are the same: The center of gravity.

A hangglider is only superficially different from an airplane because the center of lift is actively shifted by displacing the wing laterally instead of a change in lift distribution (neglecting the influence of the pilot mass on the rigging of each wing), but in all cases the vehicle will rotate around its center of gravity. Weight has no lever arm to that center of gravity, so there can be no pendulum effect. Or keel effect, fo that matter.

Comment: I've always understood that the keel effect is the roll-sideslip coupling due to pressure on surfaces above or below the cog (I.e. purely aerodynamic and not like a weighted keel). Is this not known as the keel effect, or is this not a real effect?

Comment: @Sanchises: Yes, that makes sense, but there is already the dihedral effect to occupy that slot. Granted, this name sounds as if only the wing is involved, but a fin or vertical tail (with a dihedral of 90°) shows the same effect, and for the same reason. I see no need to add yet another name, but admit that a real sailboat keel works in much the same way. In the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keel_effect) however, it is used as another name for the pendulum effect (but then it also confusingly talks of an aerodynamic side force).

Comment: Ah I suppose indeed a vertical tail "keel" is indeed just 90° dihedral. The wiki article is useless I agree. Would you consider the fuselage or pontoons dihedral (or anhedral for pontoons)?

Comment: @Sanchises No, both the fuselage and pontoons would have too little aspect ratio and too little lever arm to create much of a rolling moment. On the other hand, a low fuselage is letting the wing react like it had a bit more dihedral - that is about it for fuselages, however.

Comment: As an aside, modern hang gliders actually have a strong "aileron" effect that is an important part of roll control. The pilot's shifted weight actually pulls the "keel tube" to one side and the fabric of the left and right wings shift in an aileron-like manner.  But, that's peripheral to the main thrust of the question asked here.

Comment: @quietflyer: Absolutely correct on all counts.

Comment: @PeterKämpf "_All rotation can only happen around the center of gravity._" Airplane dont rotate about c.g. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83456/does-aircraft-allways-rotate-about-center-of-gravity-like-weather-vane-about-piv

Comment: @user207141 Accepted answers ≠ correct answers. Try to lean about conservation of momentum and don't leave thinking to others.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Dont agree with your statement that pilot dont change position of c.g.  at hang glider system, wing has mass as well. I explain this in my answer.

Comment: @PeterKämpf -- re "Now for airplanes: Here we have no pivot. All rotation can only happen around the center of gravity."  -- see my recent comments to TomMcW under my own answer-- re the fact that we can choose any arbitrary pivot point when analyzing torques.  That being the case, what does it mean to say that rotation can "only" happen about the CG?  I don't think there's any basis for such an assertion.  (Maybe grounds for a new ASE question?)  As a simple counter-example, consider a barrel roll, or a loop, or an ordinary turn.  I think that the assertion would only be true in a vacuum.

Answer (score 8):

The pendulum effect is there in high wing a/c in theory but the effect is negligible because the moment arm of the center of mass is so short relative to lateral aerodynamic center. As with dihedral, for the effect to work you have to have sideslip, and the center of mass has to be below the lateral aerodynamic center of the sideslipping fuselage so that a rolling moment is created by gravity vs the lateral force.

Best way to imagine it is the take it to the extreme; imagine a rigidly installed weight on a solid pole extending 50 feet below the fuselage.  If the airplane slideslips, there will be some lateral lift force generated opposite to the sideslip direction centered somewhere on the fuselage, and with the center of mass way below that due to the weight on the pole, the center of mass is going to want to get below the fuselage.  On a normal high wing airplane, this effect is negligible if there at all.

Not for parasails however.  Pendulum effect provides all of a parasail's lateral stability.  If a parasail starts to sideslip, your ass wants to get below it because the center of mass is down where you are and the lateral aerodynamic center is up at the wing.  The pendulum effect on a parasail is so strong that they are able to bank by skidding even though the skid is induced by ***increasing*** lift on the inside half of the wing (it's the accompanying drag that's doing the actual turning).  In other words pendulum effect overpowers the opposite rolling moment of the lowered trailing edge.

On a high wing aircraft the main effect of the configuration is aerodynamic dihedral, which is the differential lift created by sideslip where spanwise flow is obstructed below the wing but not above by the T configuration, which tends to increase the lift of the low wing.  A high wing aircraft can have sufficient self-leveling effect from aerodynamic dihedral that it can get away with no geometric dihedral, and the wing is straight, although most include some geometric dihedral as well.

A good example of this is the CL-215 waterbomber.  The wings are straight and there is sufficient dihedral effect from the T wing placement to serve the roll stability needs of the aircraft's mission.   But, when the conversion to the turboprop CL-415 was done, the flat nacelles of the PW123 engines were discovered to have a blocking effect on spanwise flow above the wing in sideslip that was equivalent to extending the fuselage above the wing, killing a lot of the aerodynamic dihedral effect.  Any pendulum effect that was there wasn't significant (if anything, the center of mass of the 415 was lower because of the lighter engines vs the R2800s of the 215).

The fix for the CL415 was one of the biggest aerodynamic band-aids I've ever seen, those odd little wingtip extensions (they are NOT winglets) which create just enough dihedral effect in sideslip to restore what was lost from the addition of the fin-like nacelles.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Canadair_CL-415_Filling.jpg

You see the opposite with high wing aircraft with sweep because there is a strong dihedral effect from the sweep itself. The combination of T configuration and sweep creates way too much dihedral effect.  So, just about all high wing airplanes with swept wings have anhedral to cancel out the excess.

Comment: All that you describe except for the last paragraph is dihedral effect. This is a completely aerodynamic effect and has nothing to do with gravity or a pendulum. What the question is getting at is whether *gravity* can cause a roll moment due to CoG being lower than the center of lift.

Comment: The first sentence answered the question.  There is an effect but it is too mild to be significant.  The rest was an explanation of why, and what "aerodynamic dihedral" is about, which is the real benefit of the high wing configuration from a lateral stability standpoint.  Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: But some people dispute that there even **is** such an effect, no matter how small. I understand all the effects due to sideslip,  but does the fact that the cg is not directly below the center of lift create a roll moment? PK made the point that the lift vector is always radial to cg, therefore can create no roll moment, no matter how far away it is

Comment: Ok I see your point. I've edited my post.  See if that helps.

Comment: "The pendulum effect on a parasail is so strong that they are able to bank by skidding even though the skid is induced by increasing lift on the inside half of the wing (it's the accompanying drag that's doing the actual turning). In other words pendulum effect overpowers the opposite rolling moment of the lowered trailing edge."-- so they are deflecting their "ailerons" the "wrong" way!  Actually I've heard that before.  PS didn't human-powered Gossamer Albatross do same?

Comment: (In that case the issue being not pendulum effect but adverse yaw and resulting roll torque due mainly to differential airspeed between left and right wings.)

Answer (score 1):

The "pendulum effect" as used in aerodynamic theory does NOT necessarily involve a weight that is free to swing. Maybe it's a poor phrase to describe what we are talking about, but it's the one that has become common. It's also a bit misleading because it implies that gravity itself is somehow exerting a direct roll torque on the aircraft.  That is not actually the case-- gravity or weight acts at the CG and so does not exert a direct roll torque.  Still, a low CG placement DOES tend to lead to a stabilizing roll torque that is much like the roll torque contributed by dihedral, sweep, etc.  All of these effects contribute a stabilizing "downwind" roll torque in the presence of sideslip.  All of these effects could be said to shift the aircraft's overall "effective dihedral"-- the relationship between sideslip and "downwind" roll torque-- in the more positive or less negative direction

Consider free-flight model airplanes with the wing on a pylon high above the fuselage.  Consider paragliders which have a strong anhedral geometry to the arched wing and yet are generally quite stable roll in roll -- as illustrated by countless stories of both deliberate and accidental cloud-flying in such aircraft with minimal instrumentation and yet with acceptable outcomes.

Note that the multiple lines connecting the paraglider pilot to the wing essentially act like fixed struts due to the triangular geometry involved.

The key to understanding the "pendulum effect" lies in understanding that a turn generally involves some sideslip (for reasons that are not simple), and that during a sideslip, the aircraft's drag force has a sideways component relative to the aircraft's longitudinal axis, and we also generate aerodynamic sideforce ("sideways lift", acting perpendicular to the lift and drag vectors) as the airflow strikes the side of the fuselage, vertical tail, etc.  Any sideways force that acts above or below the CG will contribute a roll torque.

In a paraglider, the same anhedral wing geometry that must contribute some amount of destabilizing "upwind" roll torque during a sideslip due to the difference in angle-of-attack between the left and right halves of the canopy or wing, also exposes a great deal of surface area to the sideways flow, high above the CG, contributing a stabilizing "downwind" roll torque-- the "pendulum effect".  Obviously in a paraglider, the latter dominates over the former.

High-winged aircraft benefit from enhanced roll stability due to the "pendulum effect", though there is also an additional "downwind" roll torque created by interference between the fuselage and the wings.  The latter may be absent if the wing is mounted on struts high over the fuselage-- the "parasol" configuration.

In a hang glider, the pilot hangs from a flexible strap typically connected near the aircraft CG.  In such a case, a "pendulum effect" is only present when the pilot locks himself into place with his arms-- i.e. when he uses his muscles to make a roll input.  When he is hands-free, his weight acts at the CG and there is no "pendulum effect", even though during a sideslip, his body does tend to displace slightly (a few inches) toward the "upwind" side of the control frame, just as a slip-skid ball would.  Note that the pilot's tendency to swing slightly to the upwind side of the control frame during a slip, is simply a reflection of the sideways component of the wing's drag force plus the aerodynamic sideforce generated by the wing -- if these were zero the pilot would have no tendency to deflect toward the upwind side of the control-frame, and a slip-skid ball would remain centered. (In fact, in such a case the wind would actually blow the pilot toward the other side of the control frame-- the downwind side-- during a slip.  The pilot's body would act more like a yaw string than a slip-skid ball!  This is not what we observe in practice.)

In this answer, except where specifically stated otherwise, we'll consider the hang glider in the "hands-free" case-- i.e. when the pilot is exerting zero muscle force.  The same dynamics do also affect the control inputs (muscle force) the pilot must exert to get a given result (e.g. roll rate), but we won't explore that very deeply in this answer.

On some older designs, the pilot's "hang strap" connected to the hang glider several feet below the "keel tube"-- in this case the pilot's weight acted well below the CG of the glider, and so the sideways aerodynamic forces generated by the wing during a slip did in fact contribute a stabilizing "pendulum effect".  In such a case it's equally valid to look at the pilot and the glider as separate bodies, and note the roll torque generated by the sideways pull of the pilot's hang strap on the glider, or to view the glider and pilot as one system (with the mass of the pilot considered to be located at the point where the "hang strap" connects to the glider), and note the roll torque generated by the sideways aerodynamic forces acting above the CG of the whole system.

On many modern hang gliders, the pilot's "hang strap" actually connects to the glider partway up the kingpost, or on kingpost-less gliders, on a little stub sticking several inches above the keel tube.  In this case the pilot's weight acts above the CG of the glider, so the interaction between the sideways aerodynamic forces in a slip, and the mass of the pilot, contributes a destabilizing "upwind" roll torque-- an "anti-pendulum" effect.  This is done to increase maneuverability.  Hang gliders experience substantial sideslip due to adverse yaw while rolling, so excessive "effective dihedral"-- contributing excessive "downwind" roll torque in the presence of sideslip-- is very undesirable and greatly limits the roll rate that can be achieved.

Note that the gull-shaped wing we see in many hang gliders-- especially in a view of the trailing edge-- contributes a dihedral geometry to the inboard part of the wing and an anhedral geometry to the outboard part of the wing.  Even if the net result in terms of a pure dihedral effect is zero-- which may or not be the case-- this type of design does increase the total amount of surface area exposed to the sideways airflow during a sideslip.  So the sideways aerodynamic force component during a slip will be larger with such a design, than with a completely flat wing.  This is probably best described as an unintended consequence of a wing shape that evolved for other reasons.  In some older hang gliders that had vastly more sail "billow"-- more "arch" to the trailing edge-- than today's designs, the pilot probably experienced a much larger tendency to "fall" toward the low or "upwind" side of the control frame during a sideslip, due to the increased side area exposed to the airflow.

As noted above, the relationship between bank angle, turning, and slipping is complex.  It is driven in part by the increased drag experienced by the outboard wingtip in turning flight, due to its higher airspeed.  It's a misconception to think that banking automatically generates a slip simply because weight now has a sideways component in the aircraft's frame of reference.  It's also a misconception to think that banking automatically generates a slip simply because the lift vector is now tilted relative to the earth and the wing's lift vector now has a horizontal component-- that is true in any banked turn, slipping or not.  Sometimes yaw rotational inertia may play a significant, albeit transient, role in causing sideslip.  In actual flight, in many aircraft (including hang gliders) we can observe that slip is driven overwhelmingly by roll rate, and to a much smaller extent by yaw rate.  One example of a case where we can often see substantial sideslip with no roll rate, is as we go over the top of a wingover, with a 90-degree bank angle, with no rudder input.  A complete exploration of exactly what maneuvers will involve sideslip, and to what extent, and why, is far beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: ’exposes a great deal of surface area to the sideways flow, high above the CG, contributing a stabilizing "downwind" roll torque’ Can you explain this any better? I'm not understanding what you mean here.

Comment: Imagine an aircraft with totally flat wings, as viewed head-on.  Now imagine an aircraft with gull-shaped wings, as viewed head on.  Imagine that the wingtips are no higher or lower than the wing roots, in both cases.  Won't the gull-shaped wing have more area exposed to the sideways flow during a sideslip, and thus generate more aerodynamic sideforce, than the flat wing?  I guess by "sideways flow" I'm thinking specifically of the component that goes from one wingtip toward the other-- not necessarily parallel to the horizon, if the a/c is banked.

Comment: It would produce more drag. Can't figure out where the side force would come from. Not saying it's not there, just saying I don't see what would provide it.

Comment: Isn't intuituve that a sideways wind component blowing against that big arched shape would tend to "blow" it in the downwind direction in a manner that would not simply involve a redirection, with no amplication, of the usual drag vector?  OK I see your point, do we really have a sideforce, or do we just have an amplification, as well as a redirection, of the drag vector?  Have to think about that.

Comment: Any force with a moment arm about the cog will have a rolling effect. That is entirely aerodynamic and has nothing to do with the direction of gravity, which is what a pendulum is affected by.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85052/discussion-between-tommcw-and-quiet-flyer).

Comment: Well, now it sounds like you are commenting on whether or not "pendulum effect" is really an appropriate term for what my answer focussed on.  I never at any point said that paraglider would automatically tend to respond to the gravity vector even in the absence of sideslip.

Comment: This answer mentions "gull wing" configuration, with dihedral inboard, and flat or anhedral outboard-- here's the most extreme example of that configuration that I've ever come across -- !! -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21063/what-advantages-come-with-the-wing-on-the-boeing-bird-of-prey?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @TomMcW -- (some years ago) you stated "Any force with a moment arm about the cog will have a rolling effect. That is entirely aerodynamic and has nothing to do with the direction of gravity, which is what a pendulum is affected by. "  Well, yes and no.  There's an interesting point here that goes rather deep.  To analyze the torque acting on a body, we are free to choose *any arbitrary pivot point*.  If we choose the CG for our pivot point, then the apparent weight vector (which in flight, is really the G-load vector, and if we are "pulling G's" or slipping/ skidding is different than the

Comment: (ctd) and if we are "pulling G's" or slipping/skidding is different than the *actual* weight vector), plays no role in our torque calculation.  But if we choose some other pivot point-- e.g., in some cases it might be convenient to pick as our pivot point the point where the wing's lift vector acts-- then the apparent weight vector, acting at the CG, *does* need to be included in our torque calculation.  Both approaches are valid.  Any conversation about the "pendulum effect" which overlooks this, will be doomed to go in endless circles--

Comment: (would have posted this to the chat room, but it is frozen for lack of activity.)--

Comment: Question is still apparently seen as "unresolved" after 4 years?  May need to post a whole new answer --

Answer (score 1):

Pendulum effect don`t exist in aircraft, because lift force act perpendicular to wingspan, not vertical(like at flying balloon).

When pilot move to the left, c.g. of hang glider system shift  to the left in relation to the lift line, causing lever arm between gravity and lift force, that induced roll.

It is the same like you move very heavy cargo from center to the left  in transport aircraft during level flight, aircraft will roll to the left.

Position of c.g. of hang glider system  in reference frame of earth is irrelevant here, because we are interested only at c.g. of system in relation to lift line.

Position in space of c.g. of hang glider system cant not be at same position as it was when pilot stay at center, because lateral air resistance of pilot and wing are not the same.

If we neglect lateral air resistance, then c.g. of hang glider system stay at same place.(Imagine man in space hold rock of 20kg in outstretched hand, if man pull rock toward his body, center of mass system(men+rock) must stay at same position. Center of mass system must stay at same place,because you cant translate center of mass system with internal forces.)

[image]

Comment: While the pilot can shift his personal cg relative to that of the hang glider, he cannot shoift the cg of the whole aircraft sideways without violating the conservation of momentum. When the pilot shift his cg to the left, the cg of the hang glider is shifted to the **right** and the common cg stays where it was.

Comment: @PeterKämpf Do you agree if you shift cargo from center to the left in aircraft during level flight, aircraft will roll to the left?

Comment: @PeterKämpf "_the cg of the hang glider is shifted to the right and the common cg stays where it was._" Position of c.g. of hang glider system cant not be at same position as it was when pilot stay at center, because lateral air resistance of pilot and wing are not the same. If we neglect resistance forces, then c.g. of system stay at same place.

Comment: @user207141 If you shift cargo to the left, you need to push against something (Newton's 3rd law). This something is the airplane which will be moved to the right slightly. Now the wing is shifted right while the cg is shifted left by the same amount relative to the airplane. Thus, it will create more lift on the right side and roll left. Around the cg.

Comment: @PeterKämpf I agree with you,but only if you neglect  lateral air resistance which appears when pilot move to the left and wing move to the right. Imagine diver in water hold in hands flat plate of 2m x 2m, if he pull plate toward him, c.g. of system(diver+plate) will not stay at same position because flat plate has higher drag then diver.I know this effect in air is small,but still exist. Do you agree with my logic?

Comment: Retracting all comments, will incorporate relevant ones into revised version of own answer, or replacement-- but still say all the emphasis on whether/how combined CG of glider-pilot system moves when pilot weight-shifts is "barking up the wrong tree".  A more useful question is "would the pilot have to exert a muscle force just to keep his body exactly centered in control frame during banked turning flight, and if so, in what sense does the force or roll torque exerted by his hands on the control frame represent a contribution to roll stability that might be described as a 'pendulum effect'"?

Comment: (The "barking up the wrong tree" question could actually serve as a *new ASE question*!)

Comment: @user207141 This lateral speed is so small that you can completely ignore it. In effect, it results in a tiny sideslip angle for a short moment. Water is 800 times more dense and a 2x2m plate is **much** larger than the side area of a hang glider or the human below it.

Comment: @PeterKämpf I agree with this.. Why did you say this accepted answer is not correct, can post your explanation for this topic ? https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/83456/does-aircraft-allways-rotate-about-center-of-gravity-like-weather-vane-about-piv

Comment: @user207141 Conservation of momentum means that a force is needed to change the trajectory of a mass. Without an outside force, any rotation of a hangglider must be around its cg. To say that rotations around the cg are rare is simply wrong.

Comment: @PeterKämpf When side gust hit vertical stabilizer or when aircraft roll with activated ailerons why would rotate around c.g. if these are both outside/external forces? If we exclude couple force, isnt object **only** rotate around center of mass in absence of external forces?

Comment: @user207141 Strictly yes, but the gust will create a side force (resulting in a translational movement) and a moment (weathervane stability) which results in a rotation around the cg. Since the forces ahead and aft of the cg are nearly balanced, the side force will act very near the cg, and only the long lever arm of the aerodynamic surface with the highest lift gradient (the vertical tail) will make sure that the moment is turning the aircraft into the gust.